# How would I integrate existing zend FW apps into 1 application?

Tags: php, zend-framework, integration

An existing 8+ year old application is being migrated from a self-contained website to a webservice-oriented architecture to allow among other things, external parties access to the calculations and data within the application.

The application allows visitors to access insurance-related information, calculate price quotes and contact agents.

The original logic of the application has been extracted from the main application to a SOAP service - so far, so good.

Based on in-house knowledge of Zend FW, the choice was made to drop the legacy code with many downsides and move to a more robust and community-backed framework - Zend.

An initial Zend FW app has been built that consumes the WSDL and allows searching and displaying of customers. After that was finished we wanted to integrate external applications/modules for components such as a basic (!) cms, mass-mailings, polls etc.

As we consider those components essential for the end-product but not our own core-product, we thus want to use external applications for this.

However - looking at e.g. tomatocms and digitalus etc., they seem to require us to build our product into theirs - and we want it the other way around. CMS pages are the exception, and not the rule.

Integrating authentication among these applications seems very difficult, as each seems to want to be 'the' application.

TL;DR:

What would be the best solutions to integrate a CMS or other apps into an existing/in progress zend FW app?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you is to create a structure for Modules/Plugins where you set a pattern of use and you will make your application understand these modules created following the specifications above.

With this you allow anyone to be creating or developing models desaclopados their application.

I think this is a good example with your Wordpress plugins. Anyone can create and embed its functionality within the application page, but of course you can make in its API limitations, controlling what you want.